# subview removeFromSuperview is not removing view in my function

Tags: iphone

i am developing a simple application.

in my application i have 2 views.

in one button click even i add one view as subview to the self.view.

TO remove from it i crate a method like this.

```
 - (void)validateview {
    NSLog(@"removing view");
    [seconview removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

in the another button click event i write the fallowing code.

```
[self validateview];
```

but i does n't remove view,but it prints removing view in console.

But i am trying in another button click `[seconview removeFromSuperview];`
then it works fine,it removes subview.

But i need to remove by calling

but it is not remove view validateview,because i need to validate ilike this.

i am saving a value in nsuserdefaults,

if that value is > 0 then i need to remove view else no need of removing.

how can i done can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happens:

```
- (void)validateview
{
    NSLog(@"removing view");
    NSAssert(seconview, @"can't remove seconview because it is nil");
    [seconview removeFromSuperview];
}
```